# Exponential weighting of returns

Tags: returns

I am looking for a procedure to compute an exponential weighting of returns given a half life parameter.

I ran accross a [wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponential_decay#Half-life), can I take it unchanged an assume N(t) is the return at time t ?

Comment: I don't think of return as having an exponential half-life. But if you mean return projections then we're in business. This would be more sophisticated than the rules of thumb I model with, but we're trying to capture similar concepts.

Comment: Please rephrase your title as a question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want to do sounds like exponential smoothing of returns.
So you want to forecast a return by exponentially weighting recent returns.
For exponential smoothing you can look at Hyndman's papers and the e-book or [this course](http://robjhyndman.com/uwafiles/fpp-notes.pdf) on page 34.

I personally don't think that this will give a good forecast! It would be much too easy by the way.

The link that you provide points to exponential decay. We had this in school when radio-active material got less and less. I would not just replace $N(t)$ in the wikipedia article but rather read about statistics e.g. using Hyndman's ressources (I know I cite him a lot ...).